# Sending out a newsletter - does it matter where images are hosted?

Tags: email, newsletter

I'm sending out a newsletter on icontact. Does it matter where the images in the newsletter are hosted? Would it trigger any spam filters if they come from a domain different from the email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the image is not hosted at a known spam domain, I imagine that most filters will let it through.  The problem with a question like this is that spam filters are all pretty different, so it depends on the individual recieving the newsletter.  Your best bet is probably to test it out and see if you're getting caught by the filter.